# Using pure javaScript without "onMount" in Sveltekit framework

Tags: javascript, css-animations, svelte, sveltekit

Is there a way to using simple JavaScript without using **onMount** ?
How to improve this code and don't use onMount?
(I'd like to shoe each content box after user scrolls)
[image]

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    onMount(() => {
        const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
        window.addEventListener('scroll', checkBoxes);
        checkBoxes();
        function checkBoxes() {
            const triggerBottom = (window.innerHeight / 5) * 4;
            boxes.forEach((box) => {
                const boxTop = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;

                if (boxTop < triggerBottom) {
                    box.classList.add('show');
                } else {
                    box.classList.remove('show');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your component template looks like? e.g. where is `.content` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your content boxes are generated in an array you could use a combination of `bind:this` and `svelte:window`

```html
<script>
 let boxes = [];
 let content = [];

 function checkBoxes() {
   // use boxes here
 }
</script>

<svelte:window on:scroll={checkBoxes} />

{#each content as c, i}
 <div bind:this={boxes[i]}>
   ....
 </div>
{/each}
```

Alternatively, look into actions and IntersectionObservers

Answer (score 0):

How about -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // your code here will be executed on page ready/load
});
```

Comment: This still requires `onMount` because `document` in not defined during server side rendering.